# PHP page not using new cookie values

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to use cookies in order to create a "Recently Viewed" page on my website. The pages I am tracking have code like so:

```
setcookie("pageOne", time(), time() + 3600 * 24 * 5, "/", "myurl.com");
```

The "Recently Viewed" page for now has code like:

```
$arr = [];
if (isset($_COOKIE["pageOne"])) {
    $arr[count($arr)] = "pageOne";
}
if (isset($_COOKIE["pageTwo"])) {
    $arr[count($arr)] = "pageTwo";
}
var_dump($arr);
```

I'm storing them in arrays first because later on I'd like to do some comparison on the cookie values (which is the time at viewing) in order to display x recently viewed pages.

If I visit Page One and then the Recently Viewed page, I will get the correct output

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "pageOne" }
```

When I visit Page Two, the cookie will be created, but upon going back to the Recently Viewed Page it still only displays.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "pageOne" }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have create `cookie` only for `pageOne`. Create `cookie` for `pageTwo` and then check for `cookie` if it is set or not.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can replace `$arr[count($arr)] = "pageOne";` with just `$arr[] = "pageOne";`, which is the short hand for `array_push()`.

Comment: @Virb thanks for the suggestion! The cookie for pageTwo is set, but when I revisit the "Recently Viewed" page it does not print the expected outcome (an array with both strings in it)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant set array in the direct function. it throws error message as header cannot be sent.
So Use below code in function.php to store data array in the cookie.

```html
add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_example' );
function my_setcookie_example() {
 echo "string";
 $list_value = array('pageOne' => '1','pageTwo' => '2','pageThree' => '3','pageFour' => '4' );
 setcookie( "Recpage", serialize($list_value), time() + 3600 * 24 * 5, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
```

Comment: @maulink Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this but I still have the same problem where even if I have new cookie values the Recently Visited page does not update with new values after visiting it the first time

Comment: Do one thing, in $list_value variable store cookie value & then after use array push for new current page value. that will work.